# Infinite prime in Motzkin numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The Motzkin numbers are defined by the following recurrence equation:
$$M_n=\dfrac{2n+1}{n+2}M_{n-1}+\dfrac{3n-3}{n+2}M_{n-2}$$
Only four Motzkin prime numbers are known. Is there a proof which states Motzkin prime numbers are infinite? Thanks.

Comment: Apparently this is open. Or the person who found a proof in one way or another did not brag too much about it over the internet.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motzkin_number#Properties

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit: It says : "As of October 2013, four such primes are known:
2, 127, 15511, 953467954114363 (sequence A092832 in the OEIS)". Nothing about infinite Motzkin prime numbers.

Comment: I guess @ArnaudMortier is right ... this is an open problem ... & I speculate that it will remain open for some time to come ... unless AM can persaude this person to brag on the internet.